# Refused fiancé visa uk because of financial requirements

Tags: uk-citizens

Hi I have been refused entry clearance to uk on the fiancé visa due to not meeting the financial requirement. I submitted 6 bank statements 2 mine and 4 my fiancée. With the total amount of £76,350.90 the required threshold is £62,500. But still refused because the ECO did not count the Halifax account with £ 14,560 because no recent transaction history recorded since 24/1/18. Also completely ignored the Metro bank account with balance of £ 10,300 it’s not listed in the refusal letter even. So my question is can’t you leave money sitting in the account and still be accepted by ECO? And why the Metro bank account was ignored? Can you please help thanks

Comment: Please can you upload a copy of your refusal notice, with all personal information blanked out. That will help us determine the reasons for your refusal.

Comment: @Daniel If you post a copy of the refusal letter with personal information blanked out you’ll get better answers. Were your Metro Bank statements on official Bank stationery or accompanied by a letter from the Bank confirming authenticity? See 3.3.4 https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/636618/Appendix_FM_1_7_Financial_Requirement_Final.pdf#page9 Was the Halifax statement dated January 2018 or dated within the last 6 months?

Comment: Also, do you mean that you (or your fiance) have applied to live in the UK? If so then this is the wrong site. We have a site called [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) which deals with moving to other countries. This site is about short term travel.

Comment: Hi new user.  Your question should be asked on the "Expatriates" site.  Enjoy!

Comment: But, when you post on expatriates, please give the details that have been requested above. Otherwise, people are trying to interpret your interpretation of what was said and that's just too many levels of indirection.